# Javascript remove numbers after the dot

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say i have this number: 1.5676556
But i want it to show only 1
(without rounding, lets say i have 0.6, if i use math.round, it will round it to 1)

tnx in advanced.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `Math.floor(0.6)`, or if you really want to use string manipulation, `String(0.6).split('.')[0]`.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
0.12345678.toFixed(2) // "0.12"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Math.floor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp) if the number greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `Math.trunc(7.814);`**

Do not use Math.floor or similar since they round the number instead of just removing the digits after the comma/dot.
I do not know how this has been back in the day but because of this **the accepted answer is false** nowadays.